# Are field level uniqueness constraints still supported in Mongo(ose)?

Tags: mongodb, validation, indexing, mongoose, unique

It looks like mongoose supported *field* level uniqueness constraints in earlier versions as follows (seen in 2.7.x [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html)):

```
var SomeSchema = new Schema ({
  field: {index: {unique: true}} // field level
})
```

I can't find any reference to it in the 4.4.x docs. Is the preferred way to do this on the *schema* level now, like so (seen in 4.4.x [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)):

```
SomeSchema.index({field: 1}, {unique: true}) // schema level
```

Comment: Its the same. also in 4.4.x docs you have both schema and field level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unique indexes are still supported in Mongoose; see [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-unique) and [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-index) in the current docs.

Examples from the linked docs:

```js
var s = new Schema({ date: { type: Date, index: { unique: true, expires: '1d' }});
var s = new Schema({ name: { type: String, unique: true }});

Schema.path('my.path').index({ unique: true, sparse: true });
Schema.path('name').index({ unique: true });
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Thanks for digging it up!