# Unique and index in MongooseJS?

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to enforce a unique property (email) for each user using Mongoose. Could someone explain the difference between the following two lines in MongooseJS (are they both even valid statements)?

`var userSchema = new Schema({ email: { type: String, index: { unique: true }}});`

`var userSchema = new Schema({ email: { type: String, index: true, unique: true }});`

Thank you!

Comment: I found the answer to the below question about uniqueness and indexes interesting and wanted to share it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035258/are-field-level-uniqueness-constraints-still-supported-in-mongoose/37036033#37036033 and you could read his reference links

Answer (score 0):

use unique like this , in email field

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required:true},
    mobileNumber: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true}
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```